# Is there any cleaner solution for npm build process for angular 2 app using maven?

Tags: java, maven, angular, npm

I am using Angular 2 as the frontend in a Java application with maven as the build tool. Currently, I can download node packages using `npm-maven` plugin and build Angular 2 app using `gulp` task runner. Below is my `pom` configuration

```
<execution>
    <id>install node and npm</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>${version.node}</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>${version.npm}</npmVersion>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp2.0</workingDirectory>
        <nodeDownloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
        <npmDownloadRoot>http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/</npmDownloadRoot>
    </configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
    <id>npm install</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>install --loglevel info</arguments>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp2.0</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
    <id>gulp build</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>gulp</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>build</arguments>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp2.0</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <phase>compile</phase>
</execution>
```

**Question**

The java application build process is automated using `Jenkins` and it downloads all `npm` dependencies everytime the project is built. This is unreliable because often the build gets stuck during the `npm package` download.

I am looking for a clean solution so that `npm-maven` plugin does not need to download dependencies all the time, rather, it should use `maven repository` or any such repository.

Comment: Are you using a repository manager for npm registry?

Comment: Do you clean your `Jenkins` work-space on every build? Otherwise, `npm` should recognize that the packages are already installed and won't install/download them a second time. If you are referring to the local maven-repository (on your Jenkins server) and you'd like to store the npm-packages in there, that's not possible (as far as I'm aware). If you are using a repository manager (maybe on the same server), you could add a caching there, see https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry

Comment: @Philipp Thanks for information.Yes, we do clean work-space on every build.However, `JFrog` seems to be a good option.